# Execute script from templates repository on Github Actions

Tags: yaml, sh, github-actions

I am trying to build out some pipeline templates for my team but I am having some trouble executing a common script that lives in the templates repository.

My application and actions repository structure is as follows:

App-Repo

- main.yaml -> uses `pipeline.yaml`

Template Repo

- pipeline.yaml -> `run: ./github/scripts/test.sh`
- .github/scripts/test.sh

When I run the action in the `App-Repo` it says that the file or directory is not found. The problem here is that the runner is using `App-Repo` as its directory.

I want to keep this script in the templates because it will be common across many projects.  Is there any way to pull this file/s in? Other than manually importing that repo.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Can you simply not fetch that file? Or, add template repo as a submodule?

Comment: That was my first thought, but i was hoping for a more seamless solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup a similar layout with multiple shared repositories for workflows, scripts, and composite actions.

There is no magic to have anything to be immediately available inside of a runner, so the simplest way is just to use [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) with your template repo.

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout: local'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: 'Checkout: Template Repo'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: org/templates
          path: 'templates'
      - run: ./templates/./github/scripts/test.sh
```

In this example the `path` is irrelevant, but it is where the the repo will be cloned into.

Comment: thanks - this is the approach i took.